# Find points on the hyperbola closest to the origin

Tags: calculus

I have the graph $3x^2 +10xy + 3y^2 = 9$ and I'm supposed to find the points closest to the origin.

The tangent on the point P will be orthogonal to the line that goes through the origin and point P. So first by implicit differentation I got that the slope of the tangent is $\frac{-3x_0 - 5y_0}{5x_0 + 3y_0}$

Since the lines have to be orthogonal I know the slope of the line through the origin as well so I can write it as $y = \frac{5x_0 + 3y_0}{3x_0 + 5y_0}x$

But after this I'm note sure how to proceed.

I saw this Question: [Find point nearest to the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404766/find-point-nearest-to-the-origin)

Which is basically the same as mine. Looking at Calvin Lins answer I don't understand the line: $x2+y2$ is minimized etc. I see how he uses it in the calculation and if I do the same I also get that $x = y $ and $ x=-y$ but I don't understand what he is doing and how to proceed.

Comment: You are trying to minimize $x^2+y^2 \implies 2x+2y y'=0 \implies y' = -x/y$. And you can also compute $y'$ from the given hyperbola equation. Equation them and find the values of $x$.

Comment: @MathLover But why $x^2 + y^2$, like where does that come from? I've done that and I get that $x= y$ and $x=-y$, that's when I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: The square of the distance between two points $(x,y)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ is $(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2$. In your case, $(x_1,y_1)=(0,0)$ because you are trying to minimize the distance between the origin and a point on the hyperbola.

Comment: @MathLover Oh right that formula, but I still don't understand how I'm supposed to apply $x=y$ to find the points.

Comment: Put $x=y$ in the given conic-section equation to compute the values of $y$ and $x$.

Comment: @MathLover ...ofc now I feel stupid. Thanks for the help